# PayPal payment request returns HTTP 400 response

Tags: python, paypal, httprequest

I try to make payment requesets for different users via `https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment`, but for some requests, 40%, PayPal api returns HTTP 400 response and for the rest they are fine. the body of requests is similar to:

```
{
"intent": "sale",
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "PAYPAL",
    "funding_instruments": [
        {
            "billing": {
                "billing_agreement_id": "B-XXXXX"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"transactions": [
    {
        "amount": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": "11.99",
                "tax": "0.0",
                "shipping": "0.0",
                "handling_fee": "0.0",
                "shipping_discount": "0.0",
                "insurance": "0.0"
            },
            "total": "11.99"
        },
        "invoice_number": "pp_XXXX",
        "custom": "\"{\"payment_id\": \"6102645598795\", \"user_id\": \"28233184743\", \"cid\": \"DE:282331858548:30\"}\""
    }
],
"redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
    "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel"
}
}
```

and the response is similar to

```
{
"name": "TRANSACTION_REFUSED",
"message": "The request was refused",
"information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
"debug_id": "8e0a927a12",
"code": "TRANSACTION_REFUSED"
}
```

the response is not informativ.
any idea?

Comment: It's possible this is something other than a payment decline, like a malformed request. But if that is the case, you need to share an *actual* request and response for troubleshooting. The full, exact request body, and the full exact response body -- not "similar to"

Comment: @PrestonPHX, I send the provided request and get the exact response. The sensetive numbers are just changed.

Comment: Someone may be able to help if you post an actual error, that is not a real debug_id

Comment: @PrestonPHX, how can I check it with the debug_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting PayPal support and sharing the `debug_id`, They inform me that the error is related to an invalid funding source. The issue means the funding source, credit card or bank account is deleted.